# Angular ui-grid column menu

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, right-to-left

Angular ui-grid  column menu position is false (both Chrome and Firefox).
I checked it in version 4.0.4
you can check it in tutorial: [RTL Support](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/120_RTL)

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is a bug of ui-grid
if you remove width attribute :

```
  { name: 'field1', field: 'name'},
  { name: 'field2', field: 'gender'},
  { name: 'field3', field: 'company'  },
  { name: 'field4', field: 'name'},
  { name: 'field5', field: 'gender'},
  { name: 'field6', field: 'company'},
  { name: 'field7', field: 'name'},
  { name: 'field8', field: 'gender'},
  { name: 'field9', field: 'company'},
  { name: 'field10', field: 'name'},
  { name: 'field11', field: 'gender'},
  { name: 'field12', field: 'company'},
  { name: 'field13', field: 'name'},
  { name: 'field14', field: 'gender'},
  { name: 'field15', field: 'company'}
```

you see that better than first state ,
anyway I suggest that import Ui-Grid into bootstrap to fix this bug.